# Dell laptop recognizes external monitor but does not display

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

We have a new-ish Dell Latitude E6430s laptop that has experienced all sorts of problems.  Right now, it appears to be working more or less fine, except...

When it's plugged in to the dock, nothing goes to the external monitor.  On the Displays page, it detects two external monitors (there's only one) - one's a Dell, the other is a Generic Plug and Play (the real monitor is a Dell).  If we try to select 'extend display' to either of them, nothing happens.

As far as I can tell, all drivers are up to date.  A different laptop plugged in to this dock works fine.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  This is an issue at my place of work, but we do not have an IT department - the technical people are also responsible for the IT function.  I've seen similar questions answered on this site, and I am hopeful that someone can help.

Comment: What type of dock are you using?

Comment: It's a Dell dock.  I don't have the exact model handy.  We have them all over the office.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: We don't have an IT Department. We are a small office where the developers perform IT functions, and we are stumped. Thanks for your helpful response.

Comment: Dell e6430's are known for issues with their own displays; I don't know if maybe they have issues with external ones or not.